# How can I avoid NullPointerException warning in this Java lambda expression code?

Tags: java, lambda, nullpointerexception

How can I avoid NullPointerException warning in this Java code?
I am working with IntelliJ and I am getting this warning:

> Method Invocation 'getChartController()' may produce
>   'java.Lang.NullPointerException'"

```
chartControlButtons.add(
    new JButton("Zoom In") {{
        addActionListener(
            (ActionEvent e) -> getChartController().zoomIn()
        );
    }}
);
```

Comment: How about you just check for null getChartController() before lambda expression? Or you could check null inside it as well.

Comment: you can add a try catch block around that statement and see what can be done in case of null pointer exception.

Comment: @pkgajulapalli Is `null` really an exception situation here?

Comment: Post more of your code. How does `getChartController()` look like?

Comment: Make `getChartController()` return a [null object](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) instead of null, such that invoking the method on it does nothing.

Comment: Make `getChartController()` return a [null object](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) instead of null, such that invoking the method on it does nothing.

Comment: try to use @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")

Comment: @lexicore As `getChartController()` method may return null, calling `zoomIn` method will throw a null pointer exception, right?

Comment: @pkgajulapalli Yes. But how would we know if it can return null or not if you don't post relevant code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @MartinvanWingerden That is not really a duplicate of this question. This question is asking how to fix the static analysis warning that warns the code may produce a NullPointerException.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The fact is that `getChartController` might return `null` and that is the key to understanding, and an issue which is more a full duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858721/how-can-i-fix-this-method-invocation-isemailverified-may-produce-java-lang) was marked as a duplicate of the question mentioned above. IMHO this question has been asked in many other flavors before, its harder to choose which is the best duplicate then deciding whether its a duplicate :-)

Comment: @MartinvanWingerden The OP in that question is asking about the actual occurrence of a NullPointerException (they even included the stacktrace), and not just about a static analysis warning.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I linked the wrong one, the one from which I started was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208201/cannot-resolve-method-invocation-may-produce-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use optional to avoid NullPointerExceptions.

Following is a kind of optional use this case.

```
     chartControlButtons.add(
        new JButton("Zoom In") {{
          addActionListener(
              (ActionEvent e) -> Optional.ofNullable(getChartController()).ifPresent(s -> s.zoomIn())
          );
        }}
    );
```